# What are the categories of papas in Hinduism?

Tags: sin

The Vishnudharmottara purana classifies papa into 8 distinct categories in decreasing order of their graveness

MAHANMAHATTARPATAKA,
SUMAHATTARPATAKA,
SUMAHAPATAKA,
MAHAPATAKA, 
PATAKAs, 
UPAPATAKAS,
Papa and
Kshudra papa

My question is, what are exactly are these 8 papas and patakas and parikaras suggested for the same?

Comment: I think you can link the above question in your this one and then ask only about their astrological indicators if your main enquiry is about that. Otherwise three points in your current question is already answered here.So for time being i am voting to close this question.Will retract after your re-edit :)

Comment: No my main enquiry is the exact meaning of the 8 patakas/papas and pariharas for the same. Removed astrology part in the edit. Thanks.